# Google bigquery update rows

Tags: google-bigquery

So can anyone give ideas on how to update a set of rows?

I understand the concept of query -> new table, then dumping the "old" table and re-naming the "new", but to be honest this is very hokey.

I don't see anything in the documentation, web, or in the new ideas that will lead me to believe in the appearance of an "update" statement either.

Thoughts anyone?

Comment: **2016 updated answer**: BigQuery now supports [INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922795/does-bigquery-support-update-delete-and-insert-sql-dml-statements).

Answer (score 14):

On September 29, 2016, [Google update](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/release-notes) there [DML](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-manipulation-language), and now we can write standard SQL, which enables us to insert, update, and delete rows and columns in your BigQuery datasets.

Answer (score 9):

[UPDATE This answer is out-of-date]

BigQuery does not currently support direct updates to individual rows. You can append to a table, and you can truncate/overwrite a table, but you cannot apply an update to a single row while leaving the rest of the table untouched.

The flow you mentioned (create new table, replace old table) is a reasonable approach. If it helps, note that you do not need two separate steps to replace the old table with the new table. Since BigQuery applies job side-effects atomically, you can replace the old table in one step by setting the writeDisposition on the final copy job to WRITE_TRUNCATE. For example, you could do the following:

```
  query table -> table with WRITE_TRUNCATE
```

Just like an update, you should note that this is destructive to the old table. However, if you didn't change the schema, you can use a snapshot decorator to read the table as of a time before the truncate occurred.

While this update process is occurring, you can have query jobs running against "table", and those jobs are guaranteed to see either the old content or the new content, with no inconsistent or erroneous states in between.

Comment: "In either case, while this update process is occurring, you can have query jobs running against "table", and those jobs are guaranteed to see either the old content or the new content, with no inconsistent or erroneous states in between."      Really?  That makes absolutely not sense at all.

Comment: See followup from Jordan in the answer below. Short version: BigQuery does support atomic updates, so if you run a query against a table that is about to get updated, that query will see a snapshot of the table's state either before or after the update. It will never see an empty table or a partial update. http://stackoverflow.com/a/18880082/1375400

Comment: I find the `update` method in api documentation, can you provide any example how to use it? https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/python/latest/bigquery_v2.tables.html#update

Comment: That method updates table metadata. The answer above was referring to updating a table by running a query that has a destinationTable and writeDisposition set so that it overwrites the desired table. See docs for running queries here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/querying-data?hl=en#asyncqueries

Answer (score 1):

Support for inserting, updating and deleting rows and columns have been provided by BigQuery now but only for the tables which doesn't have streaming buffer.

Comment: this answer is a bit misleading: there are no tables "which doesn't have streaming buffer" => any table can be streamed via `insertAll`(stream leagacy api) or via the new Write API. As long as there are still data in the streaming buffer those data can't be updated or deleted (it takes normally 90 minutes for BQ workers to write those data from the buffer to the columnar storage in BQ.