# Does BigQuery support UPDATE, DELETE, and INSERT (SQL DML) statements?

Tags: google-bigquery

BigQuery supports SELECT statements, but does it support DML statements like INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE?

Answer (score 32):

Yes, BigQuery now supports SQL DML with standard SQL (uncheck “Use Legacy SQL” under “Show Options”). SQL DML is not supported with legacy SQL.

Official documentation is available here:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/data-manipulation-language

**NOTE:**
UPDATE, DELETE and MERGE DML statements are supported over **tables with streaming buffer** as long as the statement doesn't affect rows that are in the streaming buffer.

Comment: the feature itself is great of course! - but i really don't think this is a right place for such announcements! i would rather expect to see it in documentation and referenced in https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/release-notes . it is already few new features available and zero official documentation and mentioning. very sad

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Official documentation is coming for this alpha release in the near future but we would like to make it available at the earliest for our users to go ahead and try so we can get your feedback.

Comment: Mikhail, I assure you that we'll have proper broad announcements when this goes Beta. This is an early Alpha release, and we hope to gather user feedback here.

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant - what do you think about using StackOverflow as our official pre-announcement channel? Everything will be documented and added to the release notes eventually, but if we have to pre-announce anywhere... why not reward our awesome StackOverflow community.

Comment: honestly! somehow I feel SO is not right place/channel for announcements! just my opinion.

Comment: Question is - where would be the place for a pre-announcement - before docs and release notes?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant - challenge: Everything will end up eventually in https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/, but we are looking for a way to share with a smaller community stuff that's not ready for prime time. We have other programs for that too, but if I had to choose my favorite is this one (including all your contributions).

Comment: Is there a mailing list or Google group? I'd happily receive such info into my inbox.

Comment: is there any API for this or the only option is BigQuery UI console?

Comment: Just want to point out that these queries have a strict daily quota so don't rely on them for ETL, etc: `Daily destination table update limit — 1,000 updates per table per day`

Answer (score 1):

I have tested a **DELETE** statement with BigQuery API, it work well for me.
this is the source code in **GCP composer (airflow)**

```
from airflow.contrib.operators.bigquery_operator import BigQueryOperator

bq_delete_task = BigQueryOperator(
    dag = dag,
    task_id = 'remove_from_table_bq',
    destination_dataset_table = False,
    destination_table = 'table_name',
    bql = "DELETE FROM " + BQ_DATASET_NAME + "." + "table_name" + " WHERE date = '2018-06-06'",
    use_legacy_sql = False
)
```